# How do I vertically center a circle on a line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a circle vertically in the middle of a horizontal line, but using a negative margin doesn't seem to work. How should I approach this?

```css
#line {
  width: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
}

#circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Value">0.33</div>
<div id="Result"></div>


<div id="line">
  <div id="circle">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just use: transform: translateY(-50%);

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
margin-left: calc(50% - 25px);
```

You can read about css calc here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Sorry I'm just trying to get it so the circle sits vertically in the middle of the line if that makes sense, so the line goes through the middle of the circle not the circle sitting on top or bottom

Comment: I don't know, but when I try that it doesnt work? The circle still sits under the line.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning and a `transform`.

```css
#line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

#circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="Value">0.33</div>
<div id="Result"></div>


<div id="line">
  <div id="circle">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are looking for this?

```css
#line {
  width: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

#circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: -25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Value">0.33</div>
<div id="Result"></div>


<div id="line">
  <div id="circle">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to move the circle to the top of the line, adjust `bottom: 0;`

Comment: Sorry I'm just trying to get it so the circle sits vertically in the middle of the line if that makes sense, so the line goes through the middle of the circle not the circle sitting on top or bottom

Comment: then you please adjust the vertical margin. in the above code just add 'margin-bottom: -25px;' for '.circle'

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:absolute` and change `margin-left:calc(50% - 25px)` and `margin-top:-22.5px` for center vertically and horizontally of line (hardcoded width and height circle)

```css
#line {
  width: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  position:relative;
}

#circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 25px);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-22.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Value">0.33</div>
<div id="Result"></div>


<div id="line">
  <div id="circle">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```