# Stop left margin pushing element off page

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/rzcos32n/

I have this code:

```js
function isItANumber(el) {

var element1 = document.getElementById("circle").innerHTML;
var percent =  parseFloat(element1)*100;
percent+='%';


  var increased = parseInt(el.innerText);
  var element = document.getElementById("Value");

  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "KanBan";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent;
  };
  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0.33) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "ScrumBan";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent;
  };
  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0.66) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Scrum";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent;
  }
    if (isNaN(increased) || element1 > 0.9) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Scrum";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginRight = '0%';
  }
}
var element = document.getElementById("circle");
isItANumber(element);
```

```css
#line {
  width: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-22.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Result"></div>


<div id="line">
  <div id="circle">
    1.0
  </div>
</div>
```

I set the position of the circle on the line horizontally depending on the percentage value in the circle. So if it's '1' that means 100%.

I do this by assigning a margin-left to it, and it works perfectly for most values, except when its a high value like 1 it pushes the circle completely off the page.

Is there a way to have it so the circle always stays on the page, even when it's margin-left is either 0% or 100%?

Comment: how about adding css `calc`? if the circle will always be `50px` width, it is a safe option -> https://jsfiddle.net/mgdraw25/1/

Comment: Do you have two accounts? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127071/how-do-i-vertically-center-a-circle-on-a-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `var percent =  "calc("+parseFloat(element1)*100+"% - 50px)";` in that way you got 100% but we have to subtract circle width (50px)

```js
function isItANumber(el) {

var element1 = document.getElementById("circle").innerHTML;
var percent =  "calc("+parseFloat(element1)*100+"% - 50px)";


  var increased = parseInt(el.innerText);
  var element = document.getElementById("Value");

  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "KanBan";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent;
  };
  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0.33) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "ScrumBan";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent;
  };
  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0.66) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Scrum";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent;
  }
    if (isNaN(increased) || element1 > 0.9) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Scrum";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginRight = '0%';
  }
}
var element = document.getElementById("circle");
isItANumber(element);
```

```css
#line {
  width: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-22.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Result"></div>
<div id="line">
  <div id="circle">
    1.0
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not needed `marginLeft` property you can use `left` property because it's a positioned element. here your accepted output or maybe it helps you.

```js
function isItANumber(el) {

var element1 = document.getElementById("circle").innerHTML;
var percent =  parseFloat(element1)*100;

percent+='%';


  var increased = parseInt(el.innerText);
  var element = document.getElementById("Value");

  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0 && element1 < 0.33 ) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "KanBan";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.left = percent;
    
  };
  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0.33 && element1 < 0.66) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "ScrumBan";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.left = percent;
    
  };
  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0.66 && element1 < 0.9) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Scrum";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.left = percent;
   
  }
    if (isNaN(increased) || element1 > 0.9) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Scrum";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.left = 'auto';
    document.getElementById("circle").style.right = '0';
  }
}
var element = document.getElementById("circle");
isItANumber(element);
```

```css
#line {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 2 */
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  position:relative;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;

}

#circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-22.5px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Result"></div>

<div id="line">
  <div id="circle">
    1.0
  </div>
</div>
```

**=== Thank you ===**

Answer (score 0):

removed javascript that is adding `100% margin-left` and replaced with `margin-left:auto` this will place the circle at the right side and used `margin-top: -22.5px` to place it on top of the line. thanks

```js
function isItANumber(el) {

  var element1 = document.getElementById("circle").innerHTML;
  var percent = parseFloat(element1) * 100;
  percent += '%';


  var increased = parseInt(el.innerText);
  var element = document.getElementById("Value");

  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "KanBan";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent;
  };
  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0.33) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "ScrumBan";
    
  };
  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 >= 0.66) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Scrum";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent;
  }
  if (isNaN(increased) || element1 > 0.9) {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Scrum";
    document.getElementById("circle").style.marginRight = '0%';
  }
}
var element = document.getElementById("circle");
isItANumber(element);
```

```css
#line {
  width: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

#circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin-top: -22.5px;
  /* margin: auto; */
  /* margin-top: 100px; */
  margin-left: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="Result"></div>


<div id="line">
  <div id="circle">
    1.0
  </div>
</div>
```